# In Whitehead and Russell's PM, when does an empty class $\Lambda$ become a member of generations $gen‘R$?

Tags: logic

Take ✳97.45 for example. I can't think of an example where $\Lambda$ is a member of $gen‘R$. I wonder if $-\Lambda$ in $gen‘R -\iota‘\Lambda$ is needed at all. Please let me know if you can think of an example. Thanks,

[image]

Note: given a field of R:

```
a  b  c  d
1  2  3  4
e  f  g  h
5  6  7  8
```

A member of $gen‘R$ is one of the **rows**, e.g. {a,b,c,d}, {1,2,3,4}...

$\overset{\rightarrow}{B}‘R$ is the first generation, ie. {a, b, c, d}.

$\overset{\leftarrow}{R_ ✳‘x}$ is "the class of descendants of x"

A member of $D‘‘\epsilon_\triangle‘\overset{\leftarrow}{R_✳}‘‘\overset{\rightarrow}{B}‘R $ is formed by selecting one out of each **column**, ie. {a,b,c,d}, {a,2,g,8},{1,2,3,4}, {1,f,7,h}, so on so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well the symbolims in ✳53.52,

> $\alpha \in \kappa - \iota‘ \Lambda$

means

> $\alpha \in \kappa . \alpha \ne \Lambda$.

In ✳53.52 we have :

$\vdash \alpha \in \kappa . \exists ! \alpha . \equiv .\alpha \in \kappa - \iota‘ \Lambda$

which I translate as "$\alpha$ is a not-empty *class*".

In the last line of the proof of ✳97.45, W&R are using ✳53.52 in order to substitute $\alpha \in gen‘R . \exists ! \alpha$ with : $\alpha \in gen‘R - \iota‘ \Lambda$, which must be read as "$\alpha$ is a not-empty member of  $gen‘R$".

Comment: That must be what they meant. Tell you the truth. Thick as the book is, I do complain about its brevity.